# Ionic 2 : Set date-time value to null

Tags: angular, date, ionic2

I try to use Date Picker with ionic and I don't know how to clear value in the input.

I want to add a value in the list to represent a "null" value : something like this :

[image]

There is my code :

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Année</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="year" doneText="Valider" cancelText="Annuler" displayFormat="YYYY"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear the value on `click` of `cancel` button (cancelText) instead.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Année</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="year" (ionCancel)="clear()" doneText="Valider" cancelText="Annuler" displayFormat="YYYY"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

**TS:**

```
clear() {
    this.year = null;
}
```